# Is there a better way to add rows of data to a master list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

This code works but it seems old-fashioned.  Is there a better way to add rows of data to a master list?

In the real-world, I often have many fields or features in each row.  Fields may be any data type, for example:

```
    Row 1: [1, 'Last Name', 101, 'Main Street', 600000, 1800.5]
```

In this simple example, there are 5 rows with two fields:

```
    Row 1:[1, 6.1101]
    Row 2:[1, 5.5277]
    Row 3:[1, 8.5186]
    Row 4:[1, 7.0032]
    Row 5:[1, 5.8598]
```

Each row is added to a master list that is converted to a numpy array:

```
    [[1.     6.1101]
     [1.     5.5277]
     [1.     8.5186]
     [1.     7.0032]
     [1.     5.8598]]
```

Here's the sample code:

```
    import numpy as np
    
    data_X = [6.1101, 5.5277, 8.5186, 7.0032, 5.8598]
    print(data_X)
    
    X1 = [1 for k in range(len(data_X))]
    
    # is there a mapping tool to replace this for loop?
    X=[]
    row=[]
    for q in range(len(data_X)):
        row.append(X1[q])
        row.append(data_X[q])
        X.append(row)
        row=[]
    print(X)
    
    X = np.array(X)
    print(X)
```

Comment: `X = np.array([[i, j] for i, j in zip(X1, data_X)])`?

Comment: In python, almost always when you see yourself doing `range(len(som_iterable))` you're making it hard on yourself.

Comment: This really looks like the kind of thing you should be using `pandas` `DataFrames` for. You might want to look into that.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll keep that in mind when using range and check out Pandas

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_X = [[X1[i], data_X[i]] for i in range(len(data_X))]
```

This just uses a list comprehension, similar to the one you've already used to create X1.

For future reference, zip() and map() are also handy built-ins which can help when manipulating lists/tuples. This article also has some useful examples on comprehensions and lists in general: https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/.

Answer (score 0):

Because numpy doesn't append well and lists do, if you need to build your list an item at a time, it's reasonable and common to append to lists.  In many situations there's a faster way though.

Once you have your data in a list there's probably going to be a better way than a loop.

For your case, I'd suggest something like:

```
ndx = np.array(data_X)
n1 = np.ones(ndx.shape)
X = np.vstack((n1, ndx)).T
```

Here, for the short data set in your example, the your list approach is actually faster.  But if I make the data longer, say 10000x longer, then numpy becomes just faster.

Here are the numbers:

data_X has **5 elements** (first list approach, then np.vstack approach):

```
3.85 µs ± 41.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
7.23 µs ± 168 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

data_X has **50,000 elements** (first list approach, then np.vstack approach):

```
26 ms ± 509 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
1.38 ms ± 6.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Another advantage of this, is that for people who are familiar with numpy, they'll understand these three lines of code at a glance.

But there are numerous ways to do this.  For example, you could also create an 2xN array of ones and then set the values in the column that contains the data, or use numpy `pad` (which maybe be faster but nobody will be able to figure out unless the read the docs, but it's there if you want to go that way).